# Testing whether an undirected graph is a forest (consists of trees) in polynomial time

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I am currently learning about forests and I am confused by this question. Is the problem of testing whether an undirected graph is a forest (i.e. an acyclic graph, or a union of disjoint trees) in the complexity class P of problems which can be solved in polynomial time?

Comment: Hint: how does the DFS traversal of a forest look like?

Comment: see this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2122485/how-to-determine-if-a-undirected-graph-is-a-forest-in-mathcalov

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this in linear time.

For most graph representations, the easiest ways are based on the observation that a connected component of N nodes is a tree iff it has exactly N-1 edges.

So just find the connected components using DFS, BFS, transitive closure, or whatever, count the nodes and edges along the way, and make sure the count comes out right.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact this can be done in linear time using a [depth first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search), or very-nearly-linear time using a [union-find data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). The latter is considerably simpler, so here's an example: the input `edges` is a list of pairs of nodes.

```py
def is_forest(edges):
    uf = UnionFind()
    for a, b in edges:
        if uf.find(a) == uf.find(b):
            return False
        uf.union(a, b)
    return True
```

Using an optimal data structure, the time complexity is O(*n* α(*n*)), where *n* is the number of edges and α is the very-slowly-growing [inverse Ackermann function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Inverse).